# What is the "l" command in Linux?

Tags: files, zsh, kali-linux, ls

I just accidentally typed `l` and hit enter. Then this happened. [image]

I'm not talking about `ls -l` just `l`.

Why did this happen?

Comment: The output of `type l` would give you a clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default `~/.zshrc`](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/kali-defaults/-/blob/kali/master/etc/skel/.zshrc) which is the customisation file of zsh, the default user shell on that system, when run interactively has:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto' # provided /usr/bin/dircolors is executable
alias l='ls -CF'
```

(see [line 220](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/kali-defaults/-/blob/d152fd3b84e8733a9ae3d6f8049394c3eb6aae5f/etc/skel/.zshrc#L220) and [246](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/kali-defaults/-/blob/d152fd3b84e8733a9ae3d6f8049394c3eb6aae5f/etc/skel/.zshrc#L246) in the current version).

So at the prompt of an interactive `zsh` shell there, unless users have modified their `~/.zshrc`, `l` would be the same as `ls --color=auto -CF`.

So that's a convenience alias provided by the system to give a more user friendly directory listing than just plain `ls`.

To verify it, you can run:

```
$ type l ls
l is an alias for ls -CF
ls is an alias for ls --color=auto
```

```
$ which l ls
l: aliased to ls -CF
ls: aliased to ls --color=auto
```

```
$ whence l ls
ls -CF
ls --color=auto
```

```
$ alias l ls
l='ls -CF'
ls='ls --color=auto'
```

The `xtrace` option can also help see what's happening when running some code:

```
$ set -o xtrace
$ cd /
+zsh:17> cd /
$ l
+zsh:18> ls '--color=auto' -CF
bin@   cdrom/  etc/   home-blank/  lib@    lib64@   lost+found/  mnt/  pool0/  root/  sbin@  srv/  tmp/  usr/
boot/  dev/    home/  home-test/   lib32@  libx32@  media/       opt/  proc/   run/   snap/  sys/  u/    var/
```

For details of what those `--color=auto`, `-C`, `-F` options do, run `man ls` or `info ls` or `ls --help`.

For information about `zsh`'s `alias`, `type`, `whence`, `which` builtin commands, run `info zsh alias`, `info zsh type`... (assuming `info` and zsh's manual in `info` format are installed on your system). You'll find the same manual online for the latest version at https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release